# Keras changing input shape for functional API - Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have trained my functional model in keras with images of dimensions 120x120 and now I would like to use this predicted model for a different shape of an input image. The common answer is to use None in the input shape, however, in my case it throws:
`Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor`
My training model is:

```
input_i = Input(shape = (120, 120, 1)) 
model = Model(input_i, all_together(input_i))
```

Once it is trained I am trying to build new model and load weights from trained one:

```
input_img = Input(shape = (None, None, 1)) 
model = Model(input_img, all_together(input_img))  <--- error
....
loading weights and so on
```

Do you have some recommendation on how to avoid this behaviour?

Numpy:1.16.4

Keras:2.3.1

Tensorflow: 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You have something in your model that does not support a variable dimension.

A `Flatten` layer, for instance. You need to use only things that support variable dimensions. A `GlobalMaxPooling2D` or a `GlobalAveragePooling2D` can be replacements for the flattening.

---

You can build your own Prelu:

```
class MyPrelu(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyPrelu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.alpha_initializer = initializers.get('zeros')
        self.alpha_regularizer = regularizers.get(None)
        self.alpha_constraint = constraints.get(None)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        param_shape = tuple(1 for i in range(len(input_shape)-1)) + input_shape[-1:]
        self.alpha = self.add_weight(shape=param_shape,
                                     name='alpha',
                                     initializer=self.alpha_initializer,
                                     regularizer=self.alpha_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.alpha_constraint)
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        pos = K.relu(inputs)
        neg = -self.alpha * K.relu(-inputs)
        return pos + neg

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    #if you want to have those initializers and other parameters, check the source code and add this:
    def get_config(.....):
        ....
```

Comment: I am using :
Conv2D
PReLU
UpSampling2D
is it possible that PReLu is that core of problem?

Comment: There is a really big change, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py#L59), they use the entire shape `input_shape[1:]` to build the parameters tensor, which even sounds bad for model performance to me.

Comment: Try with a custom prelu like above.